# How to show div element when a certain variable is chosen?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, display

I am doing a school project and I have to make a web-based browser game. Now I want DIV A to appear when someone chooses player 1, and DIV B to appear when a user chooses player 2. I cannot seem to work it out. Here is what I have got so far. I'm not quite good in JS, I hope somebody can help me out!
I defined the players at index.php, like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$playerId = $_SESSION['playerId'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if (!isset($playerId) || !isset($username)) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Session not defined!']);
    die;
}

echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'data' => [
    'playerId' => $playerId,
    'username' => $username,
]]);
```

Then, later onwards, this is the code that I want to work on the game.php page:

**The JS part**

```
// player display
var player = ['1', '2'];


if (player == '1') {
    // display #divA
} else {
    // display #divB
}
```

**The html part**

```
<div id="questionarea" style="display:none;">
    <label for="question"></label>
    <textarea name="question" id="question" placeholder="Typ hier je vraag...">
    </textarea>
    <button type="button" id="send_chat">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="divB" style="display:none;">
    <button class="col-3" type="button" id="yes">yes</button>
    <button class="col-3" type="button" id="no">no</button>
    <button class="col-3" type="button" id="maybe">maybe</button>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="divA" style="display:none;">
    <button class="col-3" type="button" id="winner" onclick="won_alert()">you won!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  element.style property to change the styles or  element.classList  to add or remove the class which can help in displaying stuff based on logic

```
if(player == "1"){
  document.querySelector('.divA').style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector('.divB').style.display = "none" ;
  }else{
  document.querySelector('.divA').style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector('.divB').style.display = "block" ;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does not yet work properly... I am defining the players on a previous page (index.php) and then lead them to game.php. I am not sure how the players can be defined properly. I saved the players in a session. Sorry, I am really really bad at this course and trying to pass it, but I don't know if I explain it correctly. This is how I get the player info on index.php: session_start();

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$playerId = $_SESSION['playerId'];

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden attribute with a condition to the div:

```
<div [hidden]="player==1"></div>
```

The div is not shown if the condition inside the double quotes is `true`

Comment: That would only work if the OP is using angular (or some other templating engine that supports this syntax), which it doesn't seem like they're doing.

Comment: Right, that was bold of me to assume that

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery here

```
if (player == '1') {
    $('.divA').css('display','block');
    $('.divB').css('display','none');
} else {
    $('.divB').css('display','block');
    $('.divA').css('display','none');
}
```